# Speed up a process of SQL query and data extraction - Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

So I am currently having some trouble with an app I am developing in eclipse. I currently have a 2 files, where by it uploads all the data from the files to a SQL database. I process this via multi threading where both files are populating simultaneously in a database and it does it relatively quick. The total number of records end up being approximately 12million in total.

After populating, a SQL query is ran in the code where by I want my records in a certain order, however, running this SQL within Java ends up taking some serious time (approximately 35 minutes or more to simply execute), before it begins dumping out the data. Ofcourse this is due to the high volume of data, but, is there a way to retain the order and dump the data in chunks, or improve the SQL somehow or some way, or literally any way to speed up this app?

```
package fedMerger;

//PREREQUISITES: ENSURE THE FOLLOWING ARE NOT DISABLED IN SERVICES MANAGEMENT WHEN RUNNING THIS UTILITY:
//SQL SERVER BROWER 
//SQL SERVER 
//SQL SERVER VSS WRITER

//BENCHMARK TEST v1 - 11million merged in 77 minutes - no multi threading
//BENCHMARK TEST v2 - 11million merged in minutes - using multi threading

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FedMerger2 extends Thread {

    private static String directory = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\Files\\";
    private static String AgentfileName = "file1.txt";
    private static String otherFileName = "file.txt";
    public static Connection connection;
    private static String mapperValue = "";
    private static String TimeStampTableName = "TimeStampTable";
    private static String timeStampColumn = "TIMESTAMP";
    private static String remainingDataColumn = "REMAINING";
    private static String user = "sa";
    private static String pass = "xxx";
    public static long timer;
    public static String Timestampquery = "INSERT INTO " + TimeStampTableName + "(" + timeStampColumn + ","
            + remainingDataColumn + ") VALUES (?,?)";
    public static String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLExpress;database=TIMESTAMP_ORGANISER;integratedSecurity=true";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
        connection = conn;
        String createTimeStampTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TimeStampTableName + "(" + timeStampColumn + " varchar(max),"
                + remainingDataColumn + " varchar(max))";
        System.out.println("Tables & Columns created - Populating data...");
        conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(createTimeStampTable);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Connection conn = connection;
            String mapperValue2 = "";
            int i = 0;
            int records = 0;
            try {
                BufferedReader agentFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory + AgentfileName));
                PreparedStatement statement = null;
                statement = conn.prepareStatement(Timestampquery);
                for (mapperValue2 = agentFile.readLine(); mapperValue2 != null; mapperValue2 = agentFile.readLine()) {
                    i++;
                    records++;
                    if (!mapperValue2.isEmpty() && mapperValue2.length() > 5) {
                        statement.setString(1, mapperValue2.substring(0, 26));
                        statement.setString(2, mapperValue2.substring(26, mapperValue2.length()));
                        statement.addBatch();
                    } else {// ignore blanks or white spaces
                        System.out.println("blank found - skipped");
                    }
                    if (i == 2500) {// Populating 100000 records at a time
                        System.out.println("executing Agent - " + records + " records...");
                        statement.executeBatch();
                        statement.clearBatch();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("executing Agent - " + records + " records...");
                statement.executeBatch();
                statement.close();
                agentFile.close();

            } catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Connection conn = connection;
            try {// Database setup and file to be read.
                BufferedReader timeStampFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(directory + otherFileName));
                int i = 0;
                int records = 0;
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(Timestampquery);
                // Dump FED info onto SQL
                for (mapperValue = timeStampFile.readLine(); mapperValue != null; mapperValue = timeStampFile.readLine()) {
                    i++;
                    records++;
                    if (!mapperValue.isEmpty() && mapperValue.length() > 5) {
                        ps.setString(1, mapperValue.substring(0, 26));
                        ps.setString(2, mapperValue.substring(26, mapperValue.length()));
                        ps.addBatch();
                    } else {// ignore blanks or white spaces
                        System.out.println("blank found - skipped");
                    }
                    if (i == 2500) {// Populating 10000 records at a time
                        System.out.println("executing timestamp - " + records + " records...");
                        ps.executeBatch();
                        ps.clearBatch();
                        i = 0;  
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("executing final " + records + " records...");
                ps.executeBatch();
                ps.clearBatch();
                i = 0;
                // Dump AGENT FED info into same SQL
                System.out.print("Uploaded to database - Working SQL query");
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(directory + "newfile" + "_MergedFinal.txt"));
                // Organise accordingly
                String retrieveData = "select " + timeStampColumn + "+" + remainingDataColumn + " as Data from "
                        + TimeStampTableName + " order by timestamp, case WHEN remaining LIKE '%agentStateEvent%' THEN -3 "
                        + "WHEN remaining LIKE '%TerminalConnectionCreated%' THEN -2 " + "ELSE -1 END";
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(retrieveData);
                ResultSet result = null;
                result = stmt.executeQuery();
                int j = 0;
                String results = "";
                System.out.println("Data organised, ready to output...");
                while (result.next()) {// SQL Query ran - Output data line by line
                    j++;
                    System.out.println("outputing data - " + j);
                    results = result.getString("data");
                    writer.write(results + "\r\n");
                    writer.flush();
                }
                writer.write(results + "\r\n");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("Done - View at " + directory + "NewFile_MergedFinal.txt");
                conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("DROP TABLE " + TimeStampTableName);
                conn.close();
                timeStampFile.close();
                System.out.print("Complete - Time taken: " + ((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timer))) + " minutes");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
        };
        //multi thread running.
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }  
}
```

Comment: The Microsoft JDBC driver buffers the _complete_ result in memory before `executeQuery()` returns to the caller. Add the parameter `;selectMethod=cursor` to your JDBC URL to avoid this and see if that improves things.

Comment: In addition to the above, I would take a guess that your database isn't indexed on the columns you're ordering by

Comment: thanks for your responses. Going to try the select method and report back. Unfortunately havent been indexed unfortunately

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, unfortunately made no difference :(

Comment: Do you need all the data?  Generally, queries to a database should return small subsets of data, or you might as well process it all locally.  Querying 12 million records is almost certainly not what you want to do -- maybe add a LIMIT or TOP clause, or if you intend to aggregate the data somehow make use of GROUP BY and HAVING clauses.  Have you tried giving the table an index on timestamp (or better yet, your complete order by clause)?

Comment: @john16384 I am doubtful that 12million records can be indexed, as I have tried this previously and keep getting a SQL error. Limit and TOP may work but it would need to be looped though, like 100-200, 300-400 to output those records at intervals

Comment: An index can certainly be added, even to a large table like this. You may want to try with an empty table, add the index, then insert your records.  Without indexes, tables of this size would be pretty useless -- you are certainly not the first person to have such large tables :)

Comment: @john16384 hehe cool, Ill give this a go now :)

Comment: Added an index now. Had  to change the "create table" for the Timestamp column from vcharmax to nvarchar(450) but it seems to be collating them nicely. Will see what the end result is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need proper index on where clause of all the columns of the query.

Secondly ,u can use some native utility to dump data way faster. example like
 bcp utility

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)
select @sql = 'bcp "select * from EmailVarification..tblTransaction"      queryout c:\bcp\Tom.xls -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername


exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```